# porque imprime todo el array?

Tags: php7

tengo un array de  3 funciones con llaves, a la hora de imprimir por ejemplo la primera función  echo $arrFunc["s"]; esta me imprime todas las llaves o cada uno de los índices del array. yo solo quiero que me imprima una sola función.

```
<?php 
//array de funciones
function saludar(){echo "hola mundo";}
function despedirse(){echo "a dios";}
function conteo(){echo "uno, dos, tres";}

$arrFunc=array("s"=>saludar(), "d"=>despedirse(), "c"=>conteo() );
echo $arrFunc["s"];


?>
```

Comment: Dentro de cada función tienes un `echo` en lugar de `return`.

Comment: El echo dentro de tu función provocará la impresión del contenido de la misma y esto será así por que dentro del array estás invocando a las funciones (*al hacer esto `"clave" => laFuncion()`*), dado lo anterior has el cambio que te indican

Comment: Tienes razón, en vez de colocar echo mejor coloco return. No se porque no había pensado esto antes. Gracias